# Download HTML table into excel using PHP

Tags: php, html, excel

I have a table on my webpage that gets populated with data based on a persons callsign. Once the data is in the table, I have a download button to download the table into an excel document. Right now when you click the button it downloads and excel file but my table is not in there. How would I populate the excel file with my table? Any thoughts or ideas are greatly appreciated!

```
<?php foreach ( $station_array as $station ) {
            $name = $station[ 'name' ];
            $temp = $station[ 'temp' ];
            $time = $station['time'];   
            $temp1 = ( ( 9 / 5 ) * $temp ) + 32;        
            echo '<table border = "1"  name = "table" class = "Choices">    
            <tr>
                <th>NO.</th>
                <th>Fields</th>
                <th>Data</th>
            </tr>
                <tr><td>1</td>
                <td>Callsign</td>
                <td>'.$name.'</td>                  
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Time</td>
                    <td>'.$time.'</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>Temperature</td>
                <td>'.$temp1.'</td>
               </tr></tabe>';?>
```

`<form class = "downLoadButton" action ="downLoad.php" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name = "submit" value="Download Data" />
        </form>`

DownLoad.php

```
<?php
  $filename = "aprsData_" . date('Ymd') . ".xls";
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
  header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");

  if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $data .= $_POST["table"];
    }

 $flag = false;
  foreach($data as $row) {
    if(!$flag) {
      // display field/column names as first row
      echo implode("\t", array_keys($row)) . "\n";
      $flag = true;
    }
    echo implode("\t", array_values($row)) . "\n";
  }
?>`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to pass contents of an html table as form data on a POST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489046/how-to-pass-contents-of-an-html-table-as-form-data-on-a-post)

Comment: naming a text file xls does not magically convert it to excel format. if you really want to create and excel file: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Comment: I guess I'm just stuck on how to get the table into the excel document then. What I have right now creates an excel file and downloads it. But there's no table or anything inside of it

Comment: it does not create an excel file at all.

Comment: It does...if you want try it. Go to http://shredmonkeyweather.com/ click weather data. Then type in KC1EML-13 and click the download button. You will see my problem.

Comment: no. file name and a type header does not change the contents of a file.

Comment: I know that, I'm asking on how to populate the excel file with my table

Comment: and i gave you a link to the library every one uses for that

Comment: Yea see thats my other problem, I'm pretty new to php so I'm not sure how to import that or what I need out of it to make this work.